# Using AWS KMS and/or credstash with non AWS server

Tags: amazon-kms

Is it possible to use AWS KMS and a tool like credstash without the use of EC2 or equivalent or does it rely solely on IAM roles?

I've got a server elsewhere where I am testing some things out and ultimately I will be looking at migrating an app to EC2 etc. to make use of scaling. But for now whilst I'm setting up my deployment pipeline etc. I wondered if it was still possible to make use of KMS on my non-aws provisioned server?

The only possible way I can think of is by installing the AWS CLI tools on the server in question. Does this sounds like the right approach?

Comment: You can use KMS from pretty much anywhere you want, even mobile applications. Apart from using the AWS CLI, you can also use any of the public AWS SDKs to perform calls to KMS. I'm happy to help with more specific pointers, but it would be nice to know more details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I basically wanted to store my database passwords etc. in kms rather than in source control and then pull them in on a server not on EC2. I don't know if we can use parameter store for this when not running on EC2 either. I think I've got the gist of it. The issue I was facing was that, if I needed to use an AWS sdk for this, then I'd most likely be storing the credentials need to initialise THAT in source control instead just moving the problem round. In terms of getting my head around though I guess an EC2 instance wouldn't cost that much to test on

Comment: KMS is not a data store. You won't be able to store your passwords on it. KMS is a general mechanism to manage encryption keys securely. Secondly, you don't need to store AWS SDK credentials if you're running in AWS. You can simply give permissions to the EC2 instance role (or another IAM role) and perform those calls using that IAM role. And last but not least, if you're comfortable using EC2, here's a great guide on how to securely store DB passwords in AWS infrastructure: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/using-iam-roles-to-distribute-non-aws-credentials-to-your-ec2-instances/

Comment: I know it’s not a data store but I was limited by comment space , but basically it would be in dynamodb using credstash or similar as mentioned in my initial post with a performing encryption. The whole point of my initial post was I wasn’t going to be running it in AWS initially either hence about then having to connect up the cli on another machine which would end up with those credentials potentially In source control. But I think for POC ec2 would be cheap enough to get this working anyway. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

What @Viccari said is correct (in the comments). In terms of what you want to do (store passwords), the AWS Parameter Store would be a good fit for you. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html for more information. The guide explicitly calls out your use-case:

> Parameter Store offers the following benefits and features.
>
> - Use a secure, scalable, hosted secrets management service (No servers to manage).

In the end, if you end up using Parameter Store or KMS, you will need some sort of credentials stored somewhere to grab an AWS STS token to use to call the underlying AWS services. If working outside of AWS EC2, you will need the AWS Access Key and AWS Secret Key from an IAM user. If you are in EC2, the IAM instance role will magically provide you the credentials and use that role to call those AWS services. The AWS SDK does this for you behind the scenes.

But, as you state, you don't want to run this in EC2 (to save money, or other reasons). The quickest way to store these credentials is to have them in a un-tracked file (added to your `.gitignore`) you can source from as environment variables, which your program will then read. This allows you to do local testing, and easily run it in EC2
with zero code changes. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html for what variables to set. Note that this doc talks about the CLI; the SDK's follow the same behavior.